# One role per user or multiple-roles per user

Tags: users

**Scenarios**: User A allows to do 1, user B allows to do 1 and 2. Assume 1 and 2 are disjoint.

*Which is better?*

**Option 1**: Create role RA can do 1, role RB can do 2, then assign user A to RA, B to both RA and RB.

**Option 2**: Create role RA can do 1, role RB can do 1 and 2, then assign user A to RA only, B to RB only.

Comment: If the Scenario is as simple as you mention then I would go with Option 2. But if there are more roles and combinations then the situation would be different.

Answer (score -1):

I would do option 1, It will give more control and maybe in the future you have a user that can only do 2.